# How do I configure ADALv3 to support switching among user IDs ... similar to Gmail?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm working with ADALv3 with Azure AD and want my ASP.NET MVC application (and Xamarin app) to support switching among different Azure AD users.

How can I configure Azure AD to support user switching as illustrated below:

[image]

Comment: Do you have still have the problem about this scenario? Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: @FeiXue-MSFT Thanks for checking in.  I've re-read your answer many times, and not sure what the effect of `context.ProtocolMessage.Parameters.Add` and how I should use cookies to accomplish this.  In reality, people will choose not only from many MSAL or ADAL accounts, but 3rd party accounts as well.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such function provide by the ADAL, we need to implement ourselves.

For example, to achieve this goal in MVC, we can save the login's username to cookies. Then we can switch the users via specify the parameter `login_hint=userName`. We need to change the `SignIn` method no matter the users are sign-in like below:

```
public void SignIn(string userName)
{          
    HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" }, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
}
```

And we can add the `login_hint` parameter via custom the `RedirectToIdentityProvider` of `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications`:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
    new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ClientId = clientId,
        Authority = authority,
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
        RedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
        {

            RedirectToIdentityProvider=context=>
            {

                var userName = context.Request.Query.Get("userName");
                context.ProtocolMessage.Parameters.Add("login_hint", userName);
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        },       
    });
```

And in the view, we need to provide the UI to switch users, here is a simple example just to demo, you can modify the code get the username of users from cookies:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Sign in-user1", "SignIn", "Account", routeValues: new { userName = "user1@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com" }, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Sign in-user2", "SignIn", "Account", routeValues: new { userName = "user2@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com" }, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
```